# Is there a web app that provides a terminal emulator / secure interface to the bash shell?

Tags: webapp-rec, windows

Is there a website where I can use the bash shell with support for xwindows, e.g. so that I can `ssh -Y` into my Linux desktop?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The 3rd party site would have to see your credentials in order to log in into your Linux box on your behalf and create a ssh emulation. This way not only you would have to trust (I'm guessing) public terminal you want to log in from but also the site. Better to start an ssh session directly from the workstation in question.

Comment: @Andris that is a good point. But how can I ssh in the scenario where I am on a public computer (e.g. I can't or don't want to install Cygwin) and would like to use bash?

Comment: I see your point. You could carry Cygwin with your [on a USB stick](http://sites.google.com/site/devinsezer/Home/software/portable-cygwin) if the public computer allows you to use it. I haven't tested this though. On the other hand if you trust the 3rd party website more then the public computer and this website would allow some form of one-time-passwords or multi factor authentication then it would be a better solution from the security standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently HTML5 enables your browser to be used as a terminal, and this is available in the Chrome web-app [secure-shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=en).

It is described [in the FAQ](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/assets.git;a=blob_plain;f=chromeapps/nassh/doc/faq.txt;hb=HEAD1) as similar to Putty, but embedded in your browser:

> "HTML Terminal", or hterm, is an xterm-compatible terminal emulator
>   written   entirely in JavaScript.
>
> It is intended to be fast enough and correct enough to compete with
>   native   terminals such as xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole and
>   Terminal.app.
>
> hterm is only a terminal emulator.  It does not provide SSH access
>   (or any   other text-based command) on its own.

This is even better than any of my previously posted solutions, any of which answered the OP.

---

- Old answer below

Here is a CW list of options:

#### Web based SSH apps

[consoleFISH](http://www.serfish.com/console/) is probably closest to what you are looking for

There is a list of both software on the Wikipedia [Web based SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Web-based_SSH&action=edit&section=7) page, including the following hosted option [consoleFish at serfish.com](http://www.serfish.com/console/)

#### weblive

This doesn't give a great answer because it is not secure, but there is a way to access a live ubuntu session using the [weblive](http://rstudio.org/download/server) interface.

Perhaps the software that runs this, [nomachine](http://www.nomachine.com/testdrive.php) has a solution.

#### rstudio

Another option is to install [R-studio server](http://rstudio.org/download/server), on a desktop or server (binaries available for Ubuntu > 10.04 or Debian > 6).

Rstudio can be accessed at `http://localhost:8787` and provides access to a shell terminal; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or `Tools > Shell`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use tightVNC

http://www.tightvnc.com/ssh-java-vnc-viewer.php